# Read, update, and create with Django REST Framework

Tags: ajax, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I have a ViewSet defined as

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

and defined my urls as

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'items', ItemViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
```

The browsable API works fine.

I want to read and send json with $.ajax(). How can I use my ViewSet to do this? I could retrieve all my items with something like `$.ajax({url: '/api/items/'})` but I don't want to hardcode the url. What if I want to edit a specific item? When I don't have a named url for the save page, then how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Read DRF docs about [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/)

Simply, you have:

```
GET     /api/items/     #list the items
POST    /api/items/     #create new item
GET     /api/items/1/   #detail info about item with id=1
PUT     /api/items/1/   #update item with id=1
PATCH   /api/items/1/   #partial-update item with id=1
DELETE  /api/items/1/   #delete item with id=1
```

Comment: But I don't have named urls. I can't hardcode all my urls

Comment: You have named urls.try `reverse('item-list')` and `reverse('item-detail', args=[1])`. This urls can be passed to javascript in order to not be hardcoded.